# Is it possible to add a stationary pop-up window to a QGIS point?

Tags: qgis, maptips

I'm a QGIS newbie, and, am just learning where to find things in QGIS.  I'm using version 3.8.  When a user clicks on a "point" in QGIS I want a window to pop-up that can contain text, a photo, and, an HTML pointer to a website.  Essentially, I want to create the equivalent of a "PlaceMark" in Google Earth and in Google Maps. I've learned how to use the "map tip" feature in QGIS already (i.e. when I hover over the icon, text and data appear. 'Map tip' is nice but I want user's to be able to click on the QGIS point and have a window open that contains static info and ability to have user re-direct to a web site.  Please let me know where I should begin my education as to how to do this, or, let me know if it is even possible.

Answer (score 5):

The feature you want is called **annotation tools**, or just "annotations". Specifically, you probably want to use HTML annotations, and possibly also SVG annotations. Annotations are available through the last button on the Attributes toolbar.

[image]

[Here's a link](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#annotation-tools) to the relevant section of the QGIS User Manual.

The HTML annotation accepts HTML code, so of course you'll need to learn some HTML as well. [Here's a link](https://html.com/) to an HTML manual. But it's probably easier to just google the specific task you're trying to accomplish, eg "html code insert image."

---

Also have a look at the **Actions** feature (follow [this link](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html) to the relevant section of the QGIS Training Manual). Actions are more complicated to set up than annotations, but they might be worth taking the time if you don't find what you need in the annotations feature.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'll learn all about the 'Annotation Tool' and the "Actions" feature. I'm just figuring out how to get started using QGIS. I'm somewhat familiar with HTML, but, will also check out the link to the manual.

Comment: Happy to help. If you want, you could post your results as an answer once you figure this all out. (Step-by-step instructions with screenshots are the best.) I find that's a great way to document the steps I took to achieve a specific result, so that I can refer back to it later. Because a year from now, you might not remember exactly how you set up that fancy map project with the HTML popups. And it helps other people who want to do the same thing.